# Are there any packages etc implementing dynamic role controller access for MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, security

I have statically allowed access to controllers/action methods using the standard Authorize attribute with roles. I am using the default ASP.Net Membership Provider.

One of our clients wants finer grained access control. They would like to be able to dynamically assign which roles can access which controllers/actions etc. I've seen answers saying implement a CustomAuthorize Attribute.

Just wondered if there were any toolkits etc to this. It seems a reasonably standard feature. I guess something like this http://kbochevski.blogspot.com/2009/11/mvc-custom-authorization.html

Comment: Any such solution would necessarily have to be too detailed to provide easily in a framework.  Only you know the layout of your tables, and how you are doing your authentication and authorization.  For example, what tables would you store the dynamic information in?

Comment: I'd have thought it would be possible. Microsoft created all the standard tables for user management why not for dynamic Action/Controller Role Based. I only need Action/Controllers which all sites have dynamically restricted by role

Comment: I think it will be more easy to take one of custome authorize solution out there and modify it to fit your problem

Comment: Well, it's certainly "possible", but so is any solution.  Microsoft has not changed the Membership and Authentication system in .NET since 2.0, and since any change could break existing code etc, they would only do so if there was a very compelling reason.  The simple answer is, that it's not part of the feature set, and any third party solution would require specific table structure that would make it difficult for most people to utilize in their existing projects, thus nobody has created a third party framework to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a custom attribute like this:

```
public class DynamicAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var controllerName = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

        // Get this string (roles) from a database or somewhere dynamic using the controllerName and actionName
        Roles = "Role1,Role2,Role3"; // i.e.  GetRolesFromDatabase(controllerName, actionName);

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Just put this attribute on any action method that requires authorization and do a look up in a database with the controller name and action name to get the required roles.

Hope this helps,

Mark